# Installing Google APIs Client Library for Java in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, json, location

I am developing an android application in eclipse that needs to use JSON, Google places API and such. But i get an error at an "@Key" annonation, and i think that i can fix this by simply installing some Google APIs Client Library for Java. But how can i install this in eclipse??? Please respond, i really need help! Thanks SO much in advance!

This is one of the java class files that has the @Key annonation error:

```
 package com.ecs.googleplaces.sample;

 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

 public class PlacesList {

     @Key
     public String status;

     @Key
     public List<place> results;

}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Simply: "Key cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to download the client library jar from Google and add it to the build path in your Eclipse project.

What I tend to do is create a "libs" directory and then copy the jar into that folder.

Then in Eclipse, right click on the project, and select Build Path -> Add Libraries and follow the wizard to add your jar.

Comment: Where can i get this client library jar file??? And what kind of library should i add? Android classpath container, JUNIT, etc?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip&can=2&q= - Download the jars from Google and then unzip the file. You want google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar. Actually you want to do Build Path -> Configure Build Path..., then do Add Jars.

Comment: Okey, i'll try that tomorrow. Dont have time now:-)

Comment: I tried now but i still get the error, why is that? I went into build path->Configure build path->Libraries->Add jars and added the jar that you specified. What can i do?

Comment: Apologies -  you actually need the google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar.